# Prahlada becoming a prisoner

Tags: mahabharata, indra, prahlada

Bianca [narrates the discourse](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b049.htm) between Prahlada and Indra, and in that Indra says to Prahlada:

> Thou art **now bound in cords, fallen off from thy former position, brought under the sway of thy foes, and divested of prosperity**. Thy present circumstances are such as may well inspire grief. Yet how is it, O Prahlada, that thou dost not indulge in grief?

Question is on the bold text above... Why Prahlada was made prisoner and what caused him to lose everything?

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is a continuation of the narration of what happened to Prahlada,[as explained in this,where Prahlada’s truth,righteousness,prosperity etc,leave him.](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a123.htm)

Indra may be referring to this abject state of Prahlada.